# Is that any way to place the VIEW button in some specify folder?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I using PHP code to auto load my folder to the website and display in the tree view.But i want to place the VIEW button in the last folder. Currently,the code will show the VIEW button on all of the folder.
The link below is the result that i want.
[I want to display something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9nxs.png)

```
<?php
$path = "2021/";
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");
list_dir($dir_handle,$path); //call the function
?>

<?php
function list_dir($dir_handle,$path)
{

    
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) 
    {
        $dir =$path.'/'.$file;
        if(is_dir($dir) && $file != '.' && $file !='..' )
        {
            $handle = @opendir($dir) or die("unable to open file $file");
            echo '<ul id="myUL">' ; //display in tree view
            echo '<li><span class="caret" >'.$file.'</span>';
            echo '<ul class="nested">';
            echo '<a href="new.php?path='.$dir.'">VIEW</a>'; //place the view button beside the folder
            list_dir($handle, $dir);
            echo '</ul>';
            echo '</li>';
            echo '</ul>';
            
        }
         
    }
   
    closedir($dir_handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding if condition

```
<?php
        $path = "2021/";
        $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");
        list_dir($dir_handle,$path); //call the function
        ?>
        
        <?php
        function list_dir($dir_handle,$path)
        {
        
            
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) 
            {
                $dir =$path.'/'.$file;
                if(is_dir($dir) && $file != '.' && $file !='..' )
                {
                    $handle = @opendir($dir) or die("unable to open file $file");
                    echo '<ul id="myUL">' ; //display in tree view
                    echo '<li><span class="caret" >'.$file.'</span>';
                    echo '<ul class="nested">';
        if($file=="100%Vi" || $file=="100%Vi") place all file names
        {
                    echo '<a href="new.php?path='.$dir.'">VIEW</a>'; 
        }
        //place the view button beside the folder
                    list_dir($handle, $dir);
                    echo '</ul>';
                    echo '</li>';
                    echo '</ul>';
                    
                }
                 
            }
           
            closedir($dir_handle);
        }
        ?>
```